# django model/modelForm - How to get dynamic choices in choiceField?

Tags: django-models, drop-down-menu, django-admin, django-forms

i'm experimenting with django and the builtin admin interface.

I basically want to have a field that is a drop down in the admin UI. The drop down choices should be all the directories available in a specified directory.
If i define a field like this:

```
test_folder_list = models.FilePathField(path=/some/file/path)
```

it shows me all the *files* in the directory, but not the *directories*.

**Does anyone know how i can display the folders?**

also i tried doing

```
test_folder_list = models.charField(max_length=100, choices=SOME_LIST)
```

where SOME_LIST is a list i populate using some custom code to read the folders in a directory. This works but it doesn't refresh. i.e. the choice list is limited to a snapshot of whatever was there when running the app for the first time.

thanks in advance.

---

update:
after some thinking and research i discovered what i want may be to either
**1.** create my own widget that is based on forms.ChoiceField
or
**2.** pass my list of folders to the choice list when it is rendered to the client

for **1.** i tried a custom widget. 
my model looks like

```
class Test1(models.Model):
    test_folder_ddl  = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

then this is my custom widget:

```
class FolderListDropDown(forms.Select):
 def __init__(self, attrs=None, target_path):
  target_folder = '/some/file/path'
  dir_contents = os.listdir(target_folder)
  directories = []
  for item in dir_contents:
   if os.path.isdir(''.join((target_folder,item,))):
    directories.append((item, item),)
  folder_list = tuple(directories)
  super(FolderListDropDown, self).__init__(attrs=attrs, choices=folder_list)
```

then i did this in my modelForm

```
class test1Form(ModelForm):
    test_folder_ddl  = forms.CharField(widget=FolderListDropDown())
```

and it didn't seem to work.What i mean by that is django didn't want to use my widget and instead rendered the default textinput you get when you use a CharField.

for **2.** I tried this in my ModelForm

```
class test1Form(ModelForm):
    test_folder_ddl = forms.CharField(widget=FolderListDropDown()) 
    test_folder_ddl.choices = {some list}
```

I also tried
    class test1Form(ModelForm):
        test_folder_ddl = forms.ChoiceField(choices={some list})

and it would still render the default char field widget.
 **Anyone know what i'm doing wrong?**

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yay solved. after beating my head all day and going through all sorts of examples by people i got this to work.

basically i had the right idea with #2. The steps are
- Create a ModelForm of our model
- override the default form field user for a models.CharField. i.e. we want to explcitly say use a choiceField.
- Then we have to override how the form is instantiated so that we call the thing we want to use to generate our dynamic list of choices
- then in our ModelAdmin make sure we explicitly tell the admin to use our ModelForm

```
class Test1(models.Model):
    test_folder_ddl  = models.CharField(max_length=100)


class Test1Form(ModelForm):
    test_folder_ddl = forms.choiceField()

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
       super(Test1Form, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
       self.fields['test_folder_ddl'].choices = utility.get_folder_list()

class Test1Admin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = Test1Form
```

Comment: Awesome, thank you so much, this works on django 1.10, too.

Answer (score 2):

I use a generator:

see git://gist.github.com/1118279.git

```
    import pysvn

    class SVNChoices(DynamicChoice):
        """
        Generate a choice from somes files in a svn repo
        """"
        SVNPATH = 'http://xxxxx.com/svn/project/trunk/choices/'
        def generate(self):
            def get_login( realm, username, may_save ):
                return True, 'XXX', 'xxxxx', True
            client = pysvn.Client()
            client.callback_get_login = get_login
            return [os.path.basename(sql[0].repos_path) for sql in client.list(self.SVNPATH)[1:]]
```