# from list to select menu in django

Tags: python, django

I thought I had it figured out but now I'm missing something.

First I have a QuerySet, records

```
records = Record.objects.all()
```

Now I want to make this into a list of one of the columns of the table, columnA

```
alist = records.values_list('columnA')
```

And then I want to pass this list in as a parameter to a custom form.

```
FilterForm(alist)
```

Here's my form

```
class FilterForm(forms.Form,list):
    numbers = forms.ChoiceField(list)
```

but keep getting an error that 'type' object is not iterable.  I'm not sure the problem has to do with the passing of the list because when I try and run this code in the shell, I get the error message when just importing the FilterForm

EDIT:  I changed my FilterForm so now it looks like this.

```
class FilterForm(forms.Form):
    def __init__(self,numbers):
        number = forms.ChoiceField(numbers)
```

so now I think it's more evident what I'm trying to do, pass in a list to the FilterForm. However when I render my template and pass the form, no form field shows up.  No error message though

EDIT EDIT: Also tried this, saw it online

```
class FilterForm(forms.Form):
    number = forms.ChoiceField()

    def __init__(self,numbers):
        super(FilterForm,self).__init__()
        self.fields['number'].choices=numbers
```

but error:

```
Exception Type:     TemplateSyntaxError
Exception Value:    

Caught ValueError while rendering: need more than 1 value to unpack
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the word `list` in this line:

```
numbers = forms.ChoiceField(list)
```

You need to provide a specific list to ChoiceField.

Comment: Ah, python is not java...What I'm trying to do is have the class take a list as a parameter.  I suppose it's not called list though.  In java I would a constructor FilterForm(List l) or something but, how is this different in python

Answer (score 0):

Here's an error:

```
class FilterForm(forms.Form,list):
    numbers = forms.ChoiceField(list)
```

You make `FilterForm` a subclass of `forms.Form` **and** `list`; then you expect `list` to be available as argument to the `ChoiceField`.

I think you are looking for dynamic `ChoiceFields`.

Further reading:

- [django model/modelForm - How to get dynamic choices in choiceField?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1387431/django-model-modelform-how-to-get-dynamic-choices-in-choicefield)